# Is there a better way other than HoG feature to recognize a real chess piece image?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using machine learning to recognize chess pieces. HoG is the feature used in my code to identify the different set of pieces, however, the results are not that accurate because of how HoG adjusts the image. Are there any other better ways to identify images, specifically chess pieces?

```
fd, hog_image = hog(img, orientations=16, pixels_per_cell=(8, 8),cells_per_block=(2, 2), visualize=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to use convolutional neural networks if you have a classification problem. For the object detection (localization + classification) You can use TensorFlow object detection API as well as YOLO models.

Here you can read more

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9

https://github.com/tensorflow/models

https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/real-time-object-detection-with-yolo-yolov2-28b1b93e2088

http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/